# need help with logparser on iis logs

Tags: windows, iis, log-files, http, logparser

I am using logparser 2.2 and need a script that does two things:

1. finding urls that contain a value within referer
2. need to loop over 30 folders

logparser -rpt:-1 "select count(*)INTO feeds.txt from u_ex100302*.log where to_lowercase(cs(Referer)) like '/feeds%'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for (1,2,3) do logparser "select count(*)INTO feeds.txt from %%i\u_ex100302*.log where to_lowercase(cs(Referer)) like '/feeds%%'"